# TypeError: option.getMember("target) is not a function

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, typeerror

So I made this kick command and I finished coding it. Now I am getting this error and have literally no idea how to fix it. I searched through the internet for an hour now and have still no idea where the issue is.

Here is the error:

```
TypeError: options.getMember is not a function
    at Object.execute (/Users/Aplex/Documents/Aplel/Commands/Moderation/kick.js:32:32)
    at Object.execute (/Users/Aplex/Documents/Aplel/Events/Interaction/interactionCreate.js:21:21)
    at Client.<anonymous> (/Users/Aplex/Documents/Aplel/Structures/Handlers/Events.js:18:54)
    at Client.emit (node:events:538:35)
    at InteractionCreateAction.handle (/Users/Aplex/Documents/Aplel/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/actions/InteractionCreate.js:74:12)
    at Object.module.exports [as INTERACTION_CREATE] (/Users/Aplex/Documents/Aplel/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/handlers/INTERACTION_CREATE.js:4:36)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (/Users/Aplex/Documents/Aplel/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketManager.js:351:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (/Users/Aplex/Documents/Aplel/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (/Users/Aplex/Documents/Aplel/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (/Users/Aplex/Documents/Aplel/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:199:18)
```

And here is my code:

```
const { Client, CommandInteraction } = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
    name: "kick",
    description: "Kick a member",
    userPermission: ["KICK_MEMBERS"],
    options: [
        {
            name: "target",
            description: "target to kick",
            type: "USER",
            required: true
        },
        {
            name: "reason",
            description: "reason for this kick",
            type: "STRING",
            required: false,
        }
    ],
    /**
     * 
     * @param {Client} client 
     * @param {CommandInteraction} interaction 
     * @param {String} args 
     */
    execute: async(client, interaction, args) => {
        const { options, member } = interaction;

        const target = options.getMember("target");
        const reason = options.getString("reason") || "No reason provided";

        if(!target.roles.highest.position >= member.roles.highest.position) return interaction.followUp({content: "You can't take action on this user as their role is higher than yours!",
    });

    await target.send(`You have been kicked from ${interaction.guild.name}, reason ${reason}`);

    target.kick(reason);

    interaction.followUp({content: `Kicked ${target.user.tag} successfully! reason: ${reason}`});
    },
};
```

Anyone know where the issue is here? It would be really appreciated if someone helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can I assume you are following lyxcode tutorials?

If so, in the line

```
execute(client, interaction, args)
```

change it to

```
execute(interaction, client, args)
```

this should then match your interactionCreate file.

also, change `followUp` to `reply`

hopefully this fixes it for you!

Comment: Thanks for this answer, it worked. But may I ask, why does it matter in the execute which order you use?

Comment: @MrAplex It matters because you basically only pass in values - the program can't match the variables by names you pass them in. So you first pass the value of the interaction, then the client, and then the args, which is the order the command file receives it. If you switch client and interaction order, the command file will think that the interaction is actually the client and the client is the interaction.

Comment: Thank you Pandicon for that answer. I really appreciate it!

Comment: @MrAplex it matters very much what order you pass arguments to a function. The function (usually) doesn't know the names of the variables you're passing it, so if you declare a function with `function fn(a, b) {...}` and pass corresponding values as `fn(bArg, aArg)`, then `fn` will assign `bArg` to `a` and `aArg` to `b`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get the member's account cache, maybe you should try something  like this:
`client.members.cache.get('User ID');`